# Combining public and private interfaces on one page

Tags: forms, inline-edit, admin, privacy

In a UI like the new YouTube what is the benefit of having a separate "Video Manager" space - where you manage all your videos/ playlists over just allowing users to perform all those functions when looking at their own profile page/ channel.

I'm working on a project where a user has a page where they can view/ manage all the things they own/ created within the site. And then a separate profile page where other users can see all the things they've created/ own within the site.

Is there any benefit of keeping that functionality in distinct spaces/ pages? I'm considering combining it all on one page ..

Comment: When the content page and editing page are separate, it's hard to visualize how your changes will look like. That's why I prefer inline editing, where you interact directly with the object. Having a separate editing page breaks my mental model - it's like I have two copies of my object and I'm interacting with one object which somehow affects the other object afar. Well, those are my two cents. I have no idea how real users feel.

Answer (score 2):

- Privacy
- Simplicity
- Content emphasis
- Speed
- Consistency

**Privacy** - If not all your content is public, seeing a different page that represents what somebody else would see is reassuring. It decreases people's anxiety that they might accidentally have made something public that was intended to be private or vice versa.

**Simplicity** - Although advanced users won't necessarily feel freaked out by seeing lots of options everywhere, new ones might. If your goal is to get as many people uploading content as possible, you don't want it to seem difficult.

**Content** - The information I want to see quickly on my profile page isn't the same as the information I want to see quickly when I'm uploading a video. But when I go to my profile, you don't have any way of knowing that my goal is to upload a video until I click an upload command. There are many other reasons I might be visiting it.

**Speed** - Since the commands people want to access when uploading are different from the ones they want to access when doing other things, making a section just for that can make it quicker to perform actions on multiple items.

**Consistency** - On some sites, users compare their own profile pages to other people's. If you don't have a way for them to see only what other people would see, they can't quickly do that type of comparison... which is essentially taking away a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I cant make a comment about what I would like or hate about your page without having a chance to see it but my biggest annoyance with the current youtube page is that it is too busy and I tend to get lost in it.

In that context,I am really glad,Youtube at least decided to separate the video manager page since it allows users to determine what belongs to them and what is from an external space or from other providers.

The biggest benefit I can see from keeping it separate is that you provide  a natural delimiter to users with regards to what they own and what is common.Further more you also enable users to have a cleaner look on your page. However I would strongly recommend that you do provide a distinctive dashboard which enables users to go their content directly without having to find out the where the link is located (as opposed to the case of youtube where I have to click under my login id to find it)

Comment: Curious,why the down vote,an elaboration would help ?